# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: generateLink is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

it said that Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: generateLink is not defined but i have generateLink funtion at the same file and call it inside while loop

```
...

const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
const page = await browser.newPage()        
await page.goto(url)
await page.waitFor(1000)  
const cafeArray = [];  
const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
   const options = document.querySelectorAll('option')
   const max = options[options.length-1].innerText
   let char = 1;
   console.log(char);
   while(char <= Number(max)) {
      link = generateLink(url, stringIncrease(String(char), Number(max)))
      cafeArray.push(link)
      char++;
   }
   const urls = getSrc(cafeArray);
   return urls
})

console.log('data:',data)
await browser.close();

return data;
}
...

function generateLink(url, page) {
   const arr = url.split('/');
   arr.pop()
   arr.push(page)

   return arr.join('/');
}
```

Comment: Where is your ```generateLink``` function declared? It is not obvious in your example

Comment: i have already defined that function above

Comment: so, it works now?

Comment: no, i try to write it on console, it work. But when i try to use puppeteer. That error appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code inside the `evaluate` is executed in the context of the browser (a.k.a. inside browser). That means that the code executed inside the browser won't see the `generateLink` function.

You could "expose" that function using `exposeFunction`.

```
await page.exposeFunction('generateLink', (url, page) => {
   const arr = url.split('/');
   arr.pop()
   arr.push(page)

   return arr.join('/');
});

const data = await page.evaluate(() => { ... });
```

Comment: Great! i fixed that. But now it said UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: Error: Protocol error (Page.navigate): Invalid parameters url: string value expected. You have any idea?

Comment: I have the same problem, I did what hardkoed said but, I can't use await because is only valid in async functions, how did it work for you?